# Get a Maven Project to work

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I'm new to Maven.
I got the latest Eclipse version (Luna for Java Developers) and installed Subversive SVN.
Then I checked out a Maven project. As it wasn't recognized as such, I converted it to "Maven Project". Afterwards I made a `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` and refreshed the project (a pom.xml appeared).
When I try to create a run configuration, it can't find a main class, although it definitely exists. In the main-tab I can browse for my project, but the windows, where I can select a main class, remains empty.
I know there is a main class in this project, but I'm not able to select it.

PS: I've also installed a local Maven repository on my machine, despite Eclipses `m2e` plugin. I don't know if it's necessary. It has even recognized it in `Windows->Preferences->Java->Build Path->Classpath Variables` as `M2_REPO (non modifiable) - C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository`. Probably from my older Eclipse instance, which came without the `m2e` plugin.

**EDIT 1: .classpath**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/mail/mail/1.4.1/mail-1.4.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.1.9.v200905050702_orbit/jaxb-api-2.1.9.v200905050702_orbit.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/4.5.0/lucene-core-4.5.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/4.5.0/lucene-core-4.5.0-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.5.0/lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queryparser/4.5.0/lucene-queryparser-4.5.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queryparser/4.5.0/lucene-queryparser-4.5.0-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queries/4.5.0/lucene-queries-4.5.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/lucene/lucene-sandbox/4.5.0/lucene-sandbox-4.5.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.1/httpclient-4.3.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3/httpcore-4.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/json-simple-1.1.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.7.8/svnkit-1.7.8.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/tmatesoft/sqljet/sqljet/1.1.6/sqljet-1.1.6.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.4/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/de/regnis/q/sequence/sequence-library/1.0.2/sequence-library-1.0.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/trilead/trilead-ssh2/1.0.0-build215/trilead-ssh2-1.0.0-build215.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/xmlrpc/xmlrpc-client/3.1.3/xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/xmlrpc/xmlrpc-common/3.1.3/xmlrpc-common-3.1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/ws/commons/util/ws-commons-util/1.0.2/ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/semanticdesktop/aperture/aperture-core/1.6.0/aperture-core-1.6.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/semanticdesktop/aperture/aperture-core/1.6.0/aperture-core-1.6.0-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/semanticdesktop/nepomuk/aperture-tools-demork/1.0.0/aperture-tools-demork-1.0.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/info/aduna/commons/aduna-commons-xml/2.6.0/aduna-commons-xml-2.6.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/info/aduna/commons/aduna-commons-text/2.6.0/aduna-commons-text-2.6.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.2/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.2/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/semweb4j/rdf2go.api/4.7.3/rdf2go.api-4.7.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.3/commons-compress-1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1.0.v20080605-1935_orbit/commons-httpclient-3.1.0.v20080605-1935_orbit.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/ronaldhttpclient/uncompressinputstream/0.3.3.aperture/uncompressinputstream-0.3.3.aperture.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/poi/poi/3.8-beta5/poi-3.8-beta5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/poi/poi-scratchpad/3.8-beta5/poi-scratchpad-3.8-beta5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.8-beta5/poi-ooxml-3.8-beta5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.8-beta5/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.3.0/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/textmining/tm-extractors/1.0-aperture.bundle/tm-extractors-1.0-aperture.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.7.0-1225586/pdfbox-1.7.0-1225586.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/pdfbox/jempbox/1.7.0-1225586/jempbox-1.7.0-1225586.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/pdfbox/fontbox/1.7.0-1225586/fontbox-1.7.0-1225586.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk14/1.44/bcmail-jdk14-1.44.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/1.44/bcprov-jdk14-1.44.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/htmlparser/htmlparser/1.6.bundle/htmlparser-1.6.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sourceforge/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3.bundle/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/mnode/ical4j/ical4j/1.0.3-java15-201109231401/ical4j-1.0.3-java15-201109231401.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/fortuna/ical4j/ical4j-vcard/0.9.3-SNAPSHOT-20110629/ical4j-vcard-0.9.3-SNAPSHOT-20110629.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/fortuna/mstor/mstor/0.9.13-SNAPSHOT-20110629/mstor-0.9.13-SNAPSHOT-20110629.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.6.1/jul-to-slf4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/2.4.0-beta1.bundle/metadata-extractor-2.4.0-beta1.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jaudiotagger/jaudiotagger/1.0.8.bundle/jaudiotagger-1.0.8.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/beetstra/jutf7/jutf7/0.9.0.bundle/jutf7-0.9.0.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sf/jacob-project/jacob/1.14.3.bundle/jacob-1.14.3.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/aetrion/flickr/flickrapi/1.2.bundle/flickrapi-1.2.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/bibsonomy/bibsonomy-rest-client/2.0.4-SNAPSHOT.bundle/bibsonomy-rest-client-2.0.4-SNAPSHOT.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/bibsonomy/bibsonomy-rest-common/2.0.4-SNAPSHOT.bundle/bibsonomy-rest-common-2.0.4-SNAPSHOT.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/bibsonomy/bibsonomy-model/2.0.4-SNAPSHOT.bundle/bibsonomy-model-2.0.4-SNAPSHOT.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/bibsonomy/bibsonomy-common/2.0.4-SNAPSHOT.bundle/bibsonomy-common-2.0.4-SNAPSHOT.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/chars/charopenhashset/5.0.9.bundle/charopenhashset-5.0.9.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/jtidy/jtidy/8.0-SNAPSHOT.bundle/jtidy-8.0-SNAPSHOT.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.9.bundle/jaxb-impl-2.1.9.bundle.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/samba/jcifs/jcifs/1.3.14/jcifs-1.3.14.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/tika/tika-core/1.1-r1221686/tika-core-1.1-r1221686.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/tika/tika-parsers/1.1-r1221686/tika-parsers-1.1-r1221686.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/xom/xom/1.2.6/xom-1.2.6.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/gov/lbl/acs/nux/nux/1.6-onelementxpath/nux-1.6-onelementxpath.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sourceforge/saxon/saxon/9.1.0.8/saxon-9.1.0.8.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sourceforge/saxon/saxon/9.1.0.8/saxon-9.1.0.8-xqj.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sourceforge/saxon/saxon/9.1.0.8/saxon-9.1.0.8-dom.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/openrdf/sesame/sesame-runtime-osgi/2.5.2-r11285-osgipatch/sesame-runtime-osgi-2.5.2-r11285-osgipatch.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/semanticdesktop/aperture/aperture-core/1.6.0/aperture-core-1.6.0-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/semweb4j/rdf2go.impl.sesame23/4.7.5-SNAPSHOT-RTGO-77/rdf2go.impl.sesame23-4.7.5-SNAPSHOT-RTGO-77.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: post `.classpath` file from your project's root directory

Comment: Do you have your source code in src/main/java? Maven expects this directory structure.

Comment: @Vwin: No, and unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the directory structure.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: goto your project's root directory, find a file named `.classpath` and post its content in your question

Comment: can you see your main class in your `PROJECT_ROOT/target/classes` ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: No, this folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

m2eclipse and the maven-eclipse-plugin are *not* compatible with each other. The maven-eclipse-plugin is an old plugin which could prepare eclipse for you, but nowadays m2eclipse is the preferred way since it integrates much much better.

Comment: I don't use maven-eclipse-plugin. The latest Eclipse instance (Java Edition) came already with m2e. The other (older) version came without any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

try updating your `.classpath` file to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" excluding="**/.svn/" path="src/main/java" output="target/classes"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" excluding="**/.svn/" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" excluding="**/.svn/" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" excluding="**/.svn/" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
            <attributes>
                <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            </attributes>
    </classpathentry>

    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: I've updated my .classpath and refreshed the project in eclipse, but it still can't find any main class.

Comment: you do clean and build that project, assumming your main class is somewhere in `PROJECT_ROOT/src/main/java`

Comment: I mistakenly posted the wrong .classpath, please see my update.  
I updated the right .classpath and adjusted the path to my main class and built it. When I run it I get the following error `The archive: /.../.../target/classes/.../... which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist` (The "..." are placeholder).

Comment: and still you have the same `.classpath` file as mine or after build it got updated ?

Answer (score -1):

Install IntelliJ IDEA CE. You will have no more problems with tools such as Maven, ANT, Gradle, Git, and many many more... :)